# diskutil no longer gives PID of dissenting process?

Tags: macos, terminal, diskutil

I recently got a new mac and simultaneously upgraded from Mojave to Monterey.

Formerly, when I ran `diskutil unmountDisk <disk here>`, if there was a dissenting process, it would provide me with the PID of the dissenter, e.g.,

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk disk4
Unmount of disk4 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted
Unmount was dissented by PID 293
```

But now this useful information seems to be nowhere to be found, i.e., the result of the above command is now simply

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk disk4
Unmount of disk4 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted
```

I'm wondering if there is still any way to recover the PID of the dissenting process(es) programmatically, whether through diskutil or some other tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lsof` command in the Terminal to see which processes have which files open. For example for your `disk4`:

```
lsof /dev/disk4
```

or if you have multiple volumes on that disk mounted:

```
lsof /dev/disk4*
```

or you can use a mount point like this:

```
lsof /Volumes/MyDisk
```

You'll get a list of open files along with the PID of the process that holds the file open. These are the processes that keeps you from unmounting the file systems.

Comment: Thanks! On my machine, `lsof /dev/disk4` prints nothing, I need to specify the partition like `/dev/disk4s2`, or the mount point `/Volumes/MyDisk`. Since there may be multiple partitions, most convenient seems to be to use a glob, e.g., `lsof /dev/disk4*`

Comment: run the `lsof` with `sudo` -- for me, without `sudo`, it prints nothing.