# diskutil unmountDisk fails, but lsof shows no processes using the disk

Tags: hard-drive, diskutil, monterey

I have a number of external hard drives with multiple partitions each.

Since getting a new Macbook Pro and updating to Monterey, running `diskutil unmountDisk` on two of these HDs fails with an error message of form `Unmount of disk5 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted`.

I expect to see this error when some process is using the disk (hence my [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/431922/211236)). However, running `lsof` prints nothing, regardless of the arguments I give it, e.g.,

```
> lsof /dev/disk5
> lsof /dev/disk5s*
> lsof /dev/disk5s2
> lsof /Volumes/Partition1
```

It is only for certain disks that `diskutil unmountDisk` gives this error; other disks unmount just fine. And even the disks that give an error can be ejected in Finder as usual (no need to force-eject or anything).

One thing that both of the disks in question have in common is that one of their partitions is a Time Machine backup. This backup is from a different computer (not the one I am running these commands on). I don't know why this would matter, but perhaps it does.

Also, `diskutil unmount` works on the individual partitions. I can even unmount every partition on a disk with `diskutil unmount disk5s2`, etc., but the attempt to run `diskutil unmountDisk disk5` still fails with the same error message. (I'm not sure whether this even really matters, as it seems I should be able to safely unplug the HD after unmounting all of its partitions.)

Comment: Have you try `sudo diskutil umountDisk force disk5`? For lsof, try `sudo lsof /dev/disk5s2`

Comment: `sudo lsof` shows a bunch of `mds` and `mds_stores` (associated with Spotlight) processes run by root, but I don't think these are causing the failure to unmount because 1) after unmounting all partitions, these processes are gone but unmount of disk still fails and 2) these processes also show up on disks that unmount just fine.

Comment: `sudo diskutil umountDisk force disk5` does work but I don't want to force unmount if there is a process that genuinely is using the disk. If necessary I guess I can write a script to check whether `lsof` has any output and if not force unmount.